# Does "when" modify the noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, interrogatives

> I will go to the beach next Saturday, so I want to know the weather at
>   the beach next Saturday.

I am trying to describe this without referring to the specific time "next Saturday".  My examples are as follows.

> 1. I want to know the weather at the beach **when** I go there.
> 2. I want to know how the weather will be at the beach **when** I go there.

I think the second one is grammatically correct, but I am not sure whether the first one is correct.  Specifically, I think the first one needs a verb such as "expected" before "when" because "when" cannot modify the noun "weather".

Comment: I'm sure you'd rather know the weather "**at** the beach" than "**in** the beach" unless you are planning on having your friends bury you in the sand.

Comment: I revised it in line with your advice.

Comment: I need to know what **the weather will be like** on Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is closest to being idiomatic

> I want to know the weather at the beach when I go.

"*there*" is implied and would be redundant.

It can also be expressed as

> I want to know the weather when I go to the beach.
>   I want to know **what** the weather will be when I go to the beach.